# AStar sometimes no way

Tags: java, algorithm, a-star

I have a very bi problem with my AStar algorithm. The point is:
If I have a start point (10,10) and the aim point is left over the start point (5,5) everything works great. But if the aim point is under or right to the startpoint (15,12) the algorithm says there is no way.

I don't know why?????

Pleas help me! I can't find the bug!

The algorithm:

```
import java.util.LinkedList;

public class AStar
{
    private OpenList openlist = new OpenList();
    private LinkedList<RasterPoint> closedList = new LinkedList<RasterPoint>();
    private LinkedList<LinkedList<RasterPoint>> raster;
    private RasterPoint endPoint;
    public LinkedList watchedRasterPoints = new LinkedList();
    public LinkedList testP = new LinkedList();
    private RasterPoint startPoint;

    public RasterPoint findWayTo(LinkedList<LinkedList<RasterPoint>> raster,int startX,int startY,int endX, int endY)
    {
        this.raster = raster;


        if(startX < 0 && startX >= raster.size()) return null;
        if(endX < 0 && endX >= raster.size()) return null;
        if(startY < 0 && startY >= raster.get(0).size()) return null;
        if(endY < 0 && endY >= raster.get(0).size()) return null;

        startPoint = raster.get(startX).get(startY);
        startPoint.setfValue(0);
        this.openlist.add(startPoint);

        endPoint = raster.get(endX).get(endY);
        // diese Schleife wird durchlaufen bis entweder
        // - die optimale Lösung gefunden wurde oder
        // - feststeht, dass keine Lösung existiert

        // die Open List ist leer, es existiert kein Pfad zum Ziel
        int num = 0;
        while(this.openlist.size() != 0 && num < 1000)
        {
            // Knoten mit dem geringsten f Wert aus der Open List entfernen
            RasterPoint currentPoint = this.openlist.popMinPoint();
            // Wurde das Ziel gefunden?
            if(currentPoint == endPoint)
            {
                return endPoint;
            }
            // Der aktuelle Knoten soll durch nachfolgende Funktionen
            // nicht weiter untersucht werden damit keine Zyklen entstehen
            this.closedList.add(currentPoint);
            // Wenn das Ziel noch nicht gefunden wurde: Nachfolgeknoten
            // des aktuellen Knotens auf die Open List setzen
            if(this.testP.contains(currentPoint))
            {
                System.out.println("Go");
            }
            this.expand(currentPoint);
            num++;
        }

        return null;
    }

    private void expand(RasterPoint currentPoint)
    {
        for(RasterPoint point : currentPoint.getSuccessorPoints(this.raster, this))
        {
            this.watchedRasterPoints.add(point);
            // wenn der Nachfolgeknoten bereits auf der Closed List ist - tue nichts
            if(this.closedList.contains(point))
            {
                return;
            }
            // g Wert für den neuen Weg berechnen: g Wert des Vorgängers plus
            // die Kosten der gerade benutzten Kante
            int gValue = currentPoint.getgValue() + 1;
            // wenn der Nachfolgeknoten bereits auf der Open List ist,
            // aber der neue Weg nicht besser ist als der alte - tue nichts
            if(this.openlist.contains(point) && gValue >= point.getgValue())
            {
                return;
            }
            // Vorgängerzeiger setzen und g Wert merken
            point.setPreRasterPoint(currentPoint);
            point.setgValue(gValue);
            // f Wert des Knotens in der Open List aktualisieren
            // bzw. Knoten mit f Wert in die Open List einfügen
            point.setfValue(gValue+point.calcHValue(this.endPoint));
            if(this.openlist.contains(point))
            {
                int position = this.openlist.indexOf(point);
                this.openlist.set(position, point);
            }
            else
            {
                this.openlist.add(point);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

And one other class:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.LinkedList;

import de.nkpmedia.rccar.floor.laserscanner.LaserPoint;

public class RasterPoint
{

    private boolean isWall;
    private LaserPoint laserPoint;
    private int fValue = 0;
    private int gValue = 0;
    private int x;
    private int y;
    /**
     * @return the preRasterPoint
     */
    public RasterPoint getPreRasterPoint()
    {
        return preRasterPoint;
    }

    /**
     * @param preRasterPoint the preRasterPoint to set
     */
    public void setPreRasterPoint(RasterPoint preRasterPoint)
    {
        this.preRasterPoint = preRasterPoint;
    }

    private RasterPoint preRasterPoint;

    /**
     * @return the gValue
     */
    public int getgValue()
    {
        return gValue;
    }

    /**
     * @param gValue the gValue to set
     */
    public void setgValue(int gValue)
    {
        this.gValue = gValue;
    }

    public RasterPoint(int rasterNumX, int rasterNumY)
    {
        this.x = rasterNumX;
        this.y = rasterNumY;
    }

    /**
     * @return the x
     */
    public int getRasterX()
    {
        return x;
    }

    /**
     * @param x the x to set
     */
    public void setRasterX(int x)
    {
        this.x = x;
    }

    /**
     * @return the y
     */
    public int getRasterY()
    {
        return y;
    }

    /**
     * @param y the y to set
     */
    public void setRasterY(int y)
    {
        this.y = y;
    }

    /**
     * @return the fValue
     */
    public int getfValue()
    {
        return fValue;
    }

    /**
     * @param fValue the fValue to set
     */
    public void setfValue(int fValue)
    {
        this.fValue = fValue;
    }

    public void setWall(boolean b)
    {
        this.isWall = b;

    }

    public void setLaserPoint(LaserPoint point)
    {
        this.laserPoint = point;

    }

    /**
     * @return the isWall
     */
    public boolean isWall()
    {
        return isWall;
    }

    /**
     * @return the laserPoint
     */
    public LaserPoint getLaserPoint()
    {
        return laserPoint;
    }

    public ArrayList<RasterPoint> getSuccessorPoints(LinkedList<LinkedList<RasterPoint>> raster, AStar aStar)
    {
        ArrayList<RasterPoint> successors = new ArrayList<RasterPoint>();
        if(this.x-1 >= 0 && this.x-1 < raster.size() && this.y >= 0 && this.y < raster.get(0).size()) successors.add(raster.get(this.x-1).get(this.y));
        if(this.x+1 >= 0 && this.x+1 < raster.size() && this.y >= 0 && this.y < raster.get(0).size()) successors.add(raster.get(this.x+1).get(this.y));
        if(this.x >= 0 && this.x < raster.size() && this.y-1 >= 0 && this.y-1 < raster.get(0).size()) successors.add(raster.get(this.x).get(this.y-1));
        if(this.x >= 0 && this.x < raster.size() && this.y+1 >= 0 && this.y+1 < raster.get(0).size()) successors.add(raster.get(this.x).get(this.y+1));
        if(aStar.testP.contains(this))
        {
            System.out.println(successors.size());
        }
        return successors;
    }

    public int calcHValue(RasterPoint endPoint)
    {
        double l = Math.sqrt(Math.pow((double)endPoint.getRasterX() - (double)this.x,2) + Math.pow((double)endPoint.getRasterY() - (double)this.y,2));
        return (int) l;
    }

}
```

If I paint all the points in the watchedRasterPoints list I can see that the algorithm adds all points which have an about 1 bigger x or y coordinates as the start point in addition to all the other points over and left to the startpoint. He also but them in the openlist.

Do you have an idea?

Thx

leet

Comment: You have a `de.nkpmedia.rccar.floor.laserscanner.LaserPoint` in your example, making this a non-mcve (http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Why not try debuging your code, going line by line...

Comment: I did. But I did not find the bug. But now I know the bug! The returns in the function expand are wrong! They terminated the whole function and because of this also the loop (  for(RasterPoint point : currentPoint.getSuccessorPoints(this.raster, this)) ) now it works

Comment: There you go. You did not find the bug, worked on it, and found the bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I write it this way it works :D The return were wrong (what a bug grrrrrr)

```
private void expand(RasterPoint currentPoint)
    {
//      this.watchedRasterPoints.add(currentPoint);
        for(RasterPoint point : currentPoint.getSuccessorPoints(this.raster, this))
        {
//          this.watchedRasterPoints.add(point);
            // wenn der Nachfolgeknoten bereits auf der Closed List ist - tue nichts
            if(this.closedList.contains(point) || point.isWall())
            {
            }
            else
            {
                // g Wert für den neuen Weg berechnen: g Wert des Vorgängers plus
                // die Kosten der gerade benutzten Kante
                int gValue = currentPoint.getgValue() + 1;
                // wenn der Nachfolgeknoten bereits auf der Open List ist,
                // aber der neue Weg nicht besser ist als der alte - tue nichts
                if(this.openlist.contains(point) && gValue >= point.getgValue())
                {
                }
                else
                {
                    // Vorgängerzeiger setzen und g Wert merken
                    point.setPreRasterPoint(currentPoint);
                    point.setgValue(gValue);
                    // f Wert des Knotens in der Open List aktualisieren
                    // bzw. Knoten mit f Wert in die Open List einfügen
                    point.setfValue(gValue+point.calcHValue(this.endPoint));
                    if(this.openlist.contains(point))
                    {
                        int position = this.openlist.indexOf(point);
                        this.openlist.set(position, point);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        floor.getModel().controller.drawRasterRect(point.getRasterX(), point.getRasterY(), Color.CYAN);
                        this.openlist.add(point);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```